# Missing Value detection fails for completely empty cells python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have created a function for which the input is a pandas dataframe.
It should return the row-indices of the rows with a missing value.
It works for all the defined Missingness values except when the cell is entirely empty - even though I tried to specify  this in the missing_values List as `[...,""]` .

What could be the issue here? Or is there even a more intuitive way to solve this in general?

```
def missing_values(x):
    df=x

    missing_values = ["NaN","NAN","NA","Na","n/a", "na", "--","-"," ","","None","0","-inf"] #common ways to indicate missingness 
    observations = df.shape[0]  # Gives number of observations (rows)
    variables = df.shape[1] # Gives number of variables (columns)

    row_index_list = []

    #this goes through each observation in the first row 
    for n in range(0,variables): #this iterates over all variables
        column_list = [] #creates a list for each value per variable
    
        for i in range(0,observations): #now this iterates over every observation per variable
            column_list.append(df.iloc[i,n]) #and adds the values to the list

        for i in range(0,len(column_list)): #now for every value
            if column_list[i] in missing_values: #it is checked, whether the value is a Missing one 
                            row_index_list.append(column_list.index(column_list[i])) #and if yes, the row index is appended

    finished = list(set(row_index_list)) #set is used to make sure the index only appears once if there are multiple occurences in one row and then it is listed

    return finished
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be spurious whitespace, so try adding `strip()` on this line:

```py
if column_list[i].strip() in missing_values: #it is checked, whether the value is a Missing one
```

Also a simpler way to get the indexes of rows containing `missing_values` is with `isin()` and `any(axis=1)`:

```py
x = x.replace('\s+', '', regex=True)
row_index_list = x[x.isin(missing_values).any(axis=1)].index
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import a file to Pandas using for example read_csv or read_excel, the missing variable (literally missing) is then can only be specify using np.nan or other type of null value with the numpy library.

(Sorry my bad right here, I was really silly when doing np.nan == np.nan)

You can replace the np.nan value first with:

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, 'NaN')
```

then your function can catch it.

Another way is to use isna() in pandas,

```
df.isna()
```

This will return the same DataFrame but with cell contains boolean value, True for each cell that is np.nan

If you do `df.isna().any()`,

This will return a Series with True value for any columns that contains null value.

If you want to retrieved the ID, simply adding the parameter axis = 1 to `any()`:

```
df.isna().any(axis = 1)
```

This will return a Series show all the rows with np.nan value.

Now you have the boolean values that indicate which row contains null values. If you add these boolean value to a list and apply that on the DF.index this will took out the index value of the rows containing null.

```
booleanlist = df.isna().any(axis =1).tolist()  
null_row_id = df.index[booleanlist]
```

Comment: keep in mind `isna` only checks for actual null values, but OP wants to check for strings ("NaN", "--", "NA", ...) which will not be considered null by `isna`

Comment: In that case, op can replace() all the value he wants to check with np.nan then follow the same steps